# How to use vertex shader via Win2d

Tags: c++, uwp, win2d, windows-8.1-universal

I've read and looked a lot of information about Win2D and found that [I can use custom pixel and vertex shaders](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win2d/archive/2014/11/05/add-sizzle-to-your-app-with-image-effects-part-3.aspx).

I found how to create custom pixel shader resource

```
        var bitmapTiger = await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(sender, "imageTiger.jpg");
        tigerSize = bitmapTiger.Size.ToVector2();

        effect = new PixelShaderEffect(await Utils.ReadAllBytes("my_pixel_shader.fxo"))
        {
            Source1 = bitmapTiger,
            Source1BorderMode = EffectBorderMode.Hard,
            Source1Mapping = SamplerCoordinateMapping.Offset,
            MaxSamplerOffset = 1
        };
```

But I can not find how to create a vertex shader resource via Win2D.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't the standard construct for HLSL vertex shaders working?

Comment: I haven't enough experience in this part of programming. I began to study it recently. I have a small project using SharpDX and I'd like to rewrite it using Win2D (for my self-learning). In SharpDX I have PixelShader and VertexShader classes. In Win2d I've found only PixelShaderEffect class

Comment: Oh, ok so you just want to use an existing shader. I thought you want to write an vertex shader, my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [site you linked](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win2d/archive/2014/11/05/add-sizzle-to-your-app-with-image-effects-part-3.aspx) stated:

> Unfortunately, it is not possible to add custom image effects to Win2D today.

This is wrong by now!
But unfortunally at the moment Win2D just offers a way to use [pixel shaders](http://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/T_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Effects_PixelShaderEffect.htm). If you want to use vertex shaders you have to use Direct3D. There is an [Example Gallery](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/win2d-example-gallery/9nblgggxwt9f) with an example how to mix Direct3D with Win2D ([the one with the teapot](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D/blob/master/samples/ExampleGallery/Shared/Direct3DInteropExample.xaml.cs)) and you can find the [code on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Win2D). I don't know if this will help you, but thats all I could find.

Comment: Thanks. Win2D is developing and I think VertexShader (like as Pixel Shader) will be implemented in the future

Comment: @AndriiKrupka I'm not sure about adding vertex shaders, because the framework is meant to get fast 2D graphics and vertex shaders are mainly for 3D graphics. But your are right it is developing, even pixel shaders are in for just about a week.